# Disable Responsive Image Sizes crop

Tags: media, responsive, cropping

I think my question might similar to others.Here is my problem, I want to **remove generating wordpress responsive images** because I have done image responsive solution with my way. So, I don't wanna save any auto generated images from wordpress in my server.

When I google it, most show how to remove from  **tag at frontend**.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to only save the original image to the server, and not have WP auto-generate additional sizes, there's a function to remove the additional sizes:

```
<?php
function wpse_remove_image_sizes() {
    // Remove the WP Core "thumbnail" size
    remove_image_size( 'thumbnail' );
    // Remove a custom image size with the slug "custom-size-name"
    remove_image_size( 'custom-size-name' );
    // Add any other sizes you need to remove -
    // this will depend on your theme and plugins.
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_remove_image_sizes');
?>
```

Proceed with caution, because many themes and some plugins use these other sizes, particularly the thumbnail.

Comment: I only want to remove responsive image that auto generated. I don't want to remove thumbnail, medium, large. And I would never remove those three size because all themes are using one of those size.